# Restore maven plugin for a project on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse

I've disabled m2eclipse plugin for a project by clicking on "Disable Maven Nature" as shown in the Figure below. Then the Maven entry disappeared from the menu and I'm unable to restore it.

[image]

How do I restore/reset/re-enable so that the entry appears again?

PS 1: I'd like to do that without re-importing the project.

PS 2: I've looked in `${WORKSPACE}/.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui` and `${WORKSPACE}/.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.m2e.core` but nothing seems related.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Solution:

Go to the project menu (right click on Package Explorer) > `Configure` > `Convert to Maven Project`

This should restore the entry in the project menu.