# ClassNotFoundException dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)

Tags: android, maven, exception

This error has come up a few times on Stackoverflow, I will reference to other questions  in this question.

My project is an Android Application using the [Android Maven Plugin](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/) to include libraries but also including some libraries locally as they are not provided via maven. My IDE is Eclipse. I have used [this tutorial mostly](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBuildMaven/article.html) to configure it. I am rather new to maven.

In short, I am unable to start the Application on my phone. When starting it I am presented with the above written Error concerning the Activity that is my start Activity called `SubscriptionView`. The entire error-trace below:

```
07-17 15:47:42.170: E/AndroidRuntime(20071): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-17 15:47:42.170: E/AndroidRuntime(20071): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dynamixsspbridge/com.example.dynamixsspbridge.SubscriptionView}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.dynamixsspbridge.SubscriptionView
07-17 15:47:42.170: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2034)
07-17 15:47:42.170: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
07-17 15:47:42.170: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
07-17 15:47:42.170: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
07-17 15:47:42.170: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-17 15:47:42.170: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-17 15:47:42.170: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
07-17 15:47:42.170: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 15:47:42.170: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-17 15:47:42.170: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
07-17 15:47:42.170: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
07-17 15:47:42.170: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-17 15:47:42.170: E/AndroidRuntime(20071): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.dynamixsspbridge.SubscriptionView
07-17 15:47:42.170: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
07-17 15:47:42.170: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
07-17 15:47:42.170: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
07-17 15:47:42.170: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
07-17 15:47:42.170: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2025)
07-17 15:47:42.170: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    ... 11 more
```

Now, there are multiple solutions for this suggested:

1. [Checking if one does in fact export private Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232851/class-loading-error-at-dalvik-system-basedexclassloader-findclassbasedexclasslo) by going to ""Build Path" -> "Configure Build Path...". 2. In the "Order and Export" Tab, Make the "Android Private Libraries" option checked. Hoping to work." I had that option checked, the error occured anyway.
2. [Make sure ProGuard does not strip classes away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686593/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-in-dalvik-system-basedexclassloader-findclass): As far as I know I do not use proguard. From what I glance one has to activly use ProGuard, its not just there... I did not. (It says "Having ProGuard run is completely optional" [on the android site](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html).) I have checked my project.properties and the proguard line there is commented out.
3. [Do not name the folder for your external libraries `lib` but `libs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824491/android-sdk-r17-ruins-working-projects). I have done so for my local libraries. The maven libraries ofcourse live wherever Maven puts them. Potentially I could take all these jars and put them from the maven repo into `libs`... then stop using maven. While this may work, it hardly presents a solution.
4. [Remove Double Libs from Build Path](http://xrigau.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/fix-some-problems-with-libraries-in-the-adt-17-plugin-10/). This is more or less the same problem described in 3. Hoever the point here is, that **"You can’t have different versions of a single library"**. Some libraries are known to provide other libs so one might be in my local folder and be provided by one of the libs added via maven. I include two libraries locally, one is not public thus if one is provided it would be *android-support-v4.jar*. I have deletet the jar, cleaned the project and exported again, no changes.
5. [Suggestions have been made, that this is actually a Eclipse problem.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40009) Restarting supposedly might ba helpful so I did. To no avail. I have tried it with and without deleting `bin` and `gen` folder.
6. [Spelling errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994210/android-maven-plugin-and-library-project)
7. Using the [m2e Plugin](http://rgladwell.github.io/m2e-android/) (already doing that)

Other Ideas that did not pan out:

**Java Version:** On of the things I feel might be responsible si my use of Java 1.5. However, while 1.6 is recommended, 1.5 should work. Switching to 1.6 does not change anything either.

**Libraries included via Maven are not exported/dexed:** Another issue I see is that the Maven Dependnecies do not show up as dexed Libraries in the folder `bin/dexedLibs`. While I believe that this is going to be an issue at a later time I have removed all classes that use these libs from the project and the error remains.

The problem is clearly somehow related to using Maven. If I create a fresh project, everything works fine until I convert the project to a maven project and add the libraries via the `pom.xml`, even if I have no classes using any of the libraries.

**EDIT** Further investigation: By creating another new project and found that on the first "right clock->configure->convert to maven" nothing is imported even after I change the `pom.xml`. [I then "disable maven nature" and then "convert to maven"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823350/restore-maven-plugin-for-a-project-on-eclipse). Now all the libraries are imported and now the error occurs. When I include the `pom.xml` into the project before converting the same error occurs.

Strangely enough, if I then "right click->maven->disable maven nature" and delete all the maven libs and files, the problem remains.

All this also happens with a fresh sample project (just the stanard activity and xml created by eclipse) after I convert to maven and the maven libs are in the project so it is apparently not related to my code at all...

The `pom.xml`looks like this

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>DynamixSSPBridge</groupId>
  <artifactId>DynamixSSPBridge</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>DynamixSSPBridge</name>
  <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
  </properties>
  <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>itm-maven-repository-releases-site</id>
            <url>https://maven.itm.uni-luebeck.de/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories> 
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
               <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
               <artifactId>android</artifactId>
               <version>2.3.3</version>
               <scope>provided</scope> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.uniluebeck.itm</groupId>
            <artifactId>ncoap</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency> 
 </dependencies>
 <build>
  <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
  <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
  <pluginManagement>
   <plugins>
    <plugin>
     <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
     <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.1.1</version>
     <extensions>true</extensions>
    </plugin>
   </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <sdk>
      <platform>9</platform>
     </sdk>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
</project>
```

Another Idea was to create a maven project with a specific android archetype as [described here](http://rgladwell.github.io/m2e-android/). However this does not seem to work as I always get an "Unable to create project from archetype" error (see picture). Creating a non android maven project was another bad try, since it isn't an android project it does not resolve the R.x references and does not dex libraries...

[image: Error message in eclipse]

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had same issue. I'd recommend you to depend on maven commands solely and not use IDE for anything (except for de-buging), because `maven-android-plugin` compiles stuff in its own way.

### Installing local jar files

You can install local libraries jar files (which not available on-line for Maven) to your local repository:

For example, here we copy `android.jar` of `4.03` which is not available on-line, to local repository on our machine:

```
mvn install:install-file \
 -Dfile=$ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-15/android.jar \
 -DgroupId=com.google.android \
 -DartifactId=android \
 -Dversion=4.0.3 \
 -Dpackaging=jar \
 -DgeneratePom=true
```

Now we can include it in POM:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>${platform.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

Maven will look in local repository and use these jar files.

### Setting correct scope

The problem of classes not being included (in my case) was caused by wrong `<scope>` of dependencies in POM. So, for all library's dependencies set `<scope>` to `compile`.

Try running `mvn clean`,`mvn install`, and `mvn:android deploy`.

Your Maven project is good only when you are able to run it from `mvn` command line without any IDE or so.

Comment: I have restarted the project and made a copy of my eclipse project after ecery single small step to know when exactly the error occurs. I have used the <scope>provided</scope> I have also included local jars as maven dependnecies via <systemPath>${project.basdir]/.../</systemPath> and made some other changes. While I do not know what exactly solved the issue the project is now working without isses so I am exepting this answer, which got me on the right track, with this comment for other users with this problem: This may or may not be the single problem but doing what S.D. says seems helpful.